# Moving an image to the side

Tags: images, css

[image]

How do I move this image on my WordPress site to the left side? I don't know which file to look for and which code to edit.

Comment: Neither do we, there's very little information here to work with, such as what theme you're using, code examples, etc

Answer (score 1):

The files are placed in theme folder at wp-content > themes > your_theme_folder 
There style.css is usually the style file which you can edit as per your requirements.

Comment: But what particular thing should I edit , and what should I change it to? To bring it to the left

Answer (score 0):

If you use google chrome you can check your code "F12".
You can use the magnifying glass and click in image. When find the class you go to your style.css and put "float: left;"

I hope help you ;)